# ChainlinkClient FetchFromArray fails to fetch price

Tags: solidity, remix, oracles, rinkeby, chainlink

Loading the fetch code from documentation:
https://docs.chain.link/docs/api-array-response/

This particular example fetched string id from that endpoint, works fine...

If instead of fetching the string id, I try to fetch current price, the fetch fails, price always displays 0

I'm using remix

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import '@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol';
import '@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ConfirmedOwner.sol';

/**
 * Request testnet LINK and ETH here: https://faucets.chain.link/
 * Find information on LINK Token Contracts and get the latest ETH and LINK faucets here: https://docs.chain.link/docs/link-token-contracts/
 */

/**
 * THIS IS AN EXAMPLE CONTRACT WHICH USES HARDCODED VALUES FOR CLARITY.
 * PLEASE DO NOT USE THIS CODE IN PRODUCTION.
 */
contract FetchFromArray is ChainlinkClient, ConfirmedOwner {
    using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;

    uint public price;

    bytes32 private jobId;
    uint256 private fee;

    event RequestPrice(bytes32 indexed requestId, uint price);

    /**
     * @notice Initialize the link token and target oracle
     *
     * Rinkeby Testnet details:
     * Link Token: 0x01BE23585060835E02B77ef475b0Cc51aA1e0709
     * Oracle: 0xf3FBB7f3391F62C8fe53f89B41dFC8159EE9653f (Chainlink DevRel)
     * jobId: 7d80a6386ef543a3abb52817f6707e3b
     *
     */
    constructor() ConfirmedOwner(msg.sender) {
        setChainlinkToken(0x01BE23585060835E02B77ef475b0Cc51aA1e0709);
        setChainlinkOracle(0xf3FBB7f3391F62C8fe53f89B41dFC8159EE9653f);
        jobId = '7d80a6386ef543a3abb52817f6707e3b';
        fee = (1 * LINK_DIVISIBILITY) / 10; // 0,1 * 10**18 (Varies by network and job)
    }

    /**
     * Create a Chainlink request to retrieve API response, find the target
     * data which is located in a list
     */
    function requestPrice() public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
        Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);

        // Set the URL to perform the GET request on
        // API docs: https://www.coingecko.com/en/api/documentation?
        req.add('get', 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&per_page=1');

        // Set the path to find the desired data in the API response, where the response format is:
        // [{
        //  "id": "bitcoin",
        //  "symbol": btc",
        //  "current_price": 22555,
        // ...
        // },
        //{
        // ...
        // .. }]
        // request.add("path", "0.id"); // Chainlink nodes prior to 1.0.0 support this format
        req.add('path', '0,current_price'); // Chainlink nodes 1.0.0 and later support this format
        // Sends the request
        return sendChainlinkRequest(req, fee);
    }

    /**
     * Receive the response in the form of string
     */
    function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, uint _current_price) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId) {
        emit RequestPrice(_requestId, _current_price);
        price = _current_price;
    }

    /**
     * Allow withdraw of Link tokens from the contract
     */
    function withdrawLink() public onlyOwner {
        LinkTokenInterface link = LinkTokenInterface(chainlinkTokenAddress());
        require(link.transfer(msg.sender, link.balanceOf(address(this))), 'Unable to transfer');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for a couple of reasons.  You're using a job ID that returns a string but what you're trying to get back is a uint256.   You referred to https://docs.chain.link/docs/api-array-response/ which returns a string value pulled out of the data object returned by the API call.

Instead you want a uint256.  You can get the correct JobIDs for the testnet oracles from [this link](https://docs.chain.link/docs/any-api-testnet-oracles/)

Change as follows:

```
// jobId = '7d80a6386ef543a3abb52817f6707e3b'; --> returns string
jobId = 'ca98366cc7314957b8c012c72f05aeeb'; ----> returns uint256
```

This jobId is used in [this example](https://docs.chain.link/docs/single-word-response/) but note that the tasks/steps are a bit different.

At the URL that sets out the JobIds,  the table under "JOBS" includes the a "TASKS" column that specifies the tasks (steps) to be done.  When you return a uint256 you need to include an additional task in your code - the Multiply Task (its linked in the table).

So to your`requestPrice()` method you need to also add:

```
...

req.add('path', '0,current_price'); // Chainlink nodes 1.0.0 and later support this format

// Multiply the result by 1 to get the int returned in the response.
req.addInt('times', 1);        ---------> add this
...
```

The `addInt` method documentation is [here](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-framework/#methods-2)

By making these two changes I was able to make it work.